# How to treat text field as URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called `Store` with a table column named `website` and it suppose to link to external websites. A user types in the store website (e.g. www.newegg.com or http://www.newegg.com) and then it will be clickable in a view to send other users to it.

I've tried doing:

```
<%= link_to store.website %>
```

But this obviously just links back to the same page.

How would you make a text_field or string column be read as a URL? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe:

```
<%= link_to store.website, store.website %>
```